# Launch standalone Maya with UI from within Maya

Tags: python, pyqt, maya

I bit more than I could chew and I need your help.

Basically I'm writing a script that is launched from within Autodesk Maya.

I have UI window with a text field and a button to set the path to a folder under it there is a QPushButton to launch a batch process.

Here is the UI script

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
import maya.mel as mel


presetPathName = "C:/Users/Valeriya/Documents/maya/scripts/CHanimExport/UMA_Male_Rig_AnimationExport.fbxexportpreset"
USERAPPDIR = cmds.internalVar(userAppDir=True)
DIRECTORY = os.path.join(USERAPPDIR, 'processedAnimation')



def load_fbx_export_preset(presetPathName):
    mel.eval('loadPlugin "fbxmaya";')
    mel.eval('FBXLoadExportPresetFile -f "{}";'.format(presetPathName))



class batch_cleanup_UI(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(batch_cleanup_UI, self).__init__()
        self.anim_folder_path = None
        self.export_dir = DIRECTORY
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Batch Joint CleanUp")
        self.setObjectName("BatchJointCleanUpID")
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 100)
        self.setMaximumSize(800, 200)
        self.resize(400, 100)
        
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(5)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.text_field_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.text_field_layout)

        self.batch_btn_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.batch_btn_layout)

    # Text Line
        self.nameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('Animation Folder:')
        self.text_field_layout.addWidget(self.nameLabel)
        self.saveNameField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.text_field_layout.addWidget(self.saveNameField)
        self.btn_set_path = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Set Path")
        self.btn_set_path.clicked.connect(self.btn_set_path_clicked)
        self.text_field_layout.addWidget(self.btn_set_path)

    # Batch Btn 
        self.btn_batch_process = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Batch Fix")
        self.btn_batch_process.clicked.connect(self.btn_batch_process_clicked)
        self.batch_btn_layout.addWidget(self.btn_batch_process)

    def btn_set_path_clicked(self):
        anim_folder_path = cmds.fileDialog2(dialogStyle=2, fileMode=3)
        if anim_folder_path:
            selected_folder_path = anim_folder_path[0]
            self.saveNameField.setText(selected_folder_path)
            self.anim_folder_path = selected_folder_path  # Set the attribute here
        return anim_folder_path
    
    def createDirectory(directory=DIRECTORY):
        '''
        Creates a given Directory if it doesn't exist
        Args:
            directory(str):The directory to create
        '''
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.mkdir(directory)
        return directory


    def btn_batch_process_clicked(self):
        if not self.anim_folder_path:
            cmds.warning("Please set the animation folder path.")
            return

        fbx_files = [f for f in os.listdir(self.anim_folder_path) if f.endswith('.fbx')]
        if not fbx_files:
            cmds.warning("No FBX files found in the specified folder.")
            return

        for fbx_file in fbx_files:
            full_path = os.path.join(self.anim_folder_path, fbx_file)
            self.open_fbx_file(full_path)

    def open_fbx_file(self, file_path):
        # Load the FBX export preset
        load_fbx_export_preset(presetPathName)

        # Import the FBX file
        cmds.file(file_path, i=True, type="FBX", ignoreVersion=True, ra=True, mergeNamespacesOnClash=False, namespace=":")

        # Perform additional operations if needed
        file_short_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        file_name = file_short_name.split(".")[0]

        # Open Files in a given folder
        for joint in joint_list:
            cmds.cutKey(joint, attribute=['translateX', 'translateY', 'translateZ'], option="keys")

        # Save the file to overwrite it in the same folder
        cmds.select('ParentForExportDelete', hierarchy=True)
        nameExport = os.path.join(self.export_dir, file_name + '.fbx')
        cmds.FBXExport(s=True, f=nameExport, force=True, options=True)



def clean_ui():
    if cmds.window("BatchJointCleanUpID", exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("BatchJointCleanUpID", window=True)

    if cmds.windowPref("BatchJointCleanUpID", exists=True):
        cmds.windowPref("BatchJointCleanUpID", remove=True)

clean_ui()
win = batch_cleanup_UI()
win.show()
```

and the second script is to launch standalone Maya to do the batch process:

```py
import os
from maya.standalone import standalone
from maya.cmds import cmds
import maya.mel as mel
from AnimJntClnup import batch_cleanup_UI



joint_list = ['Leg_L','Knee_L','Foot_L','Toe_L']


standalone.initialize(name="python")
path = batch_cleanup_UI.self.anim_folder_path

for f in files:
    cmds.file(f, open=True, type='FBX', force=True)
    #cmds.file(f, open=True)

    file_short_name = os.path.basename(f)
    file_name = file_short_name.split(".")[0]

    #Open Files in a given folder


    for joint in joint_list:


        cmds.cutKey( joint, attribute=['translateX', 'translateY', 'translateZ'], option="keys" )



    # Save the file to overwrite it
    nameExport = path + '/' + file_name + '.fbx'
    mel.eval('file -force -options "fbx" -type "FBX export" -pr -ea "{}";'.format(nameExport))

    print("/n/n/nOutput:/n")
    print("/n" + file_name + "=>" + "Saved here => " + nameExport)



#print(file_name)

standalone.uninitialize()
```

Basically I want to launch the second script with the "Batch" button from the first one.
Can anyone teach me how to do this?

Comment: I don't know exactly how mel works, if it needs the context of a running Maya app or it can work standalone (and whether `mel` commands are run in a separate process or not), so it would be better if you could clarify those aspects. In any case, the second script won't work because you're trying to rely on `batch_cleanup_UI`, which is a class. The `self` attribute you're trying to access doesn't exist, because `self` represents a reference to the current instance within instance methods (the functions implemented in a class). That can only be done by using a function that accepts arguments.

Comment: Do a preliminary research. What did you try? See [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html).